# Difference between image dataset representation in Tensorflow and Theano

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, theano

According to the following code snippet from this [repo](https://github.com/dandxy89/ImageModels/blob/master/AlexNet_Original.py#L82)

```
# Define image input layer
if DIM_ORDERING == 'th':
    INP_SHAPE = (3, 224, 224)  # 3 - Number of RGB Colours
    img_input = Input(shape=INP_SHAPE)
    CONCAT_AXIS = 1
elif DIM_ORDERING == 'tf':
    INP_SHAPE = (224, 224, 3)  # 3 - Number of RGB Colours
    img_input = Input(shape=INP_SHAPE)
    CONCAT_AXIS = 3
```

The shape of the input data is being decided based on the backend to be used with Keras library. I wanted to know that why this distinction is necessary? Why can't we use the same input shape in both the cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Keras` is a high-level deep learning API for both `tensorflow` and `theano`. It's using a functions from these libraries in order to perform computations. In `Theano` - its autors decided to put the channels dimension before spatial ones. In `Tensorflow` - authors put it as the last dimension. This is the reason behind the difference in `Keras` which you mentioned.

Comment: Can you explain why on this line (https://github.com/fchollet/keras/blob/97174dd298cf4b5be459e79b0181a124650d9148/keras/layers/normalization.py#L83) this assumption has been made that the image dataset has been represented as [image_index, channels, rows, cols]

Comment: This is a version from August 2015 when Theano was the only `backend` available.

Comment: I didn't see LRN2D layer available in Keras anywhere now. If I just change the position of the channel then will the same code work for Keras with tensor flow? I am working on reproducing the results of AlexNet therefore I am looking for this layer

Comment: Because today `BatchNormalization` is belived to be the best and using `LRN2D` is considered as a depreciated method of normalization.